# How do I download tweet texts from tweet IDs in R?

Tags: r, twitter

I have large tsv-files containing the tweet-IDs of millions of tweets which I would like to content analyze in R. How do I get the meta data of the tweets (message, user, date etc) into a dataset without looking up every individual tweet?

I know this is possible in Python, is it also possible to do it in R since I do not know Python well. Is there a R package for this purpose?

Comment: maybe this: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/twitteR/versions/1.1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the rTweet library (which is usually preferred over twitteR, as the latter is no longer maintained), you can use the `lookup_statuses` function to get the metadata for large batches of Tweets.

Comment: Thanks very much, however I have also problems with using the `lookup_statuses` function. This would be my code:
```
sampletweets <- lookup_statuses(daytwo.sample$tweet_id, parse = TRUE, token = NULL)
#Error in tw_from_response(out, ...) : unused arguments (parse = TRUE, token = NULL)
```
I cant explain the error message here..